# How To Parse Emails WITHOUT Depending On 3rd Party Script?

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a PHP Web Application and I am trying to figure out how to parse HTML Emails into the application without relying on a 3rd Party Script since I can not afford a new server. Essentially what needs to occur is that a Lead Company sends an HTML Email with the Lead's information (Name, Telephone number, Address, Type Of Lead, and 2 other text based fields). I need the software to extract that information and create a New Lead in the application for this information.

Server has PHP 5.2. Linux. With 2 MySQL Databases.

Comment: Well if the email is always in a specified format, i would advise to write a script to parse the email and extract this data.

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mails arrive into an IMAP e-mail account, the PHP IMAP functions give you quite a nice access to the e-mail parts.